# Checking for the Variant value "Nothing"

Tags: delphi, excel, automation, ms-office

This is something I ran into last year, and SO seems like a good place to document it :)

Q: When automating Excel (/Word/...) from Delphi, how can I check if an Excel function returned the variant `Nothing` (as it's called in VBA)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`VarIsClear`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Variants.VarIsClear) function includes your situation where the type is `varDispatch` and the value is `nil`. It also includes empty and "unknown" values, and custom variant types. I see it in my Delphi 2005 source; I don't know how much earlier it was included.

Comment: ?! You're right! I completely overlooked that one! I've accepted your answer, and will change my source code ;-) Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4):

Curiously, VBA's `Nothing` is *not* the same as `Unassigned`, `Null` or `Empty`, so you can't use, e.g.:

```
// Worksheet is a TExcelWorksheet or OleVariant coupled to an open worksheet
MyRange := Worksheet.Range['MyRangeInTheWorksheet', EmptyParam]
if (MyRange = Null) then  // won't work!
  MsgBox('The range doesn''t exist!');
```

Instead, use this function:

```
function VarIsNothing(V: OleVariant): Boolean;
begin
  Result :=
    (TVarData(V).VType = varDispatch)
    and
    (TVarData(V).VDispatch = nil);
end;

// ...

if (VarIsNothing(MyRange)) then
```

---

**Update**

Apparently, the sources of the RTL unit `Variants.pas` have changed between Delphi 5 and 2007. According to @mghie (see comments), the function `VarIsEmpty` would have done the job in D5. However, in D2007, this does not seem to be the case anymore, so you'll probably need the above function again.

Also, note that VBA's `Nothing` is probably quite a special case; I don't think one encounters it too often with automation.

Comment: @onnodb: If replacing "(MyRange = Null) " with "VarIsNull(MyRange) or VarIsEmpty(MyRange)" works I'd politely suggest accepting Craig's answer. No need to write custom functions for stuff that is already in the library and documented.

Comment: @mghie: I'm pretty sure those do *not* work with that pesky `Nothing` value :)

Comment: @onnodb: Well, have a look at the source code of VarIsEmpty() - it is a superset of your code, at least in the Delphi 5 version I'm looking at right now...

Comment: @mghie: Curious... My D2007 sources say `Result := FindVarData(V)^.VType = varEmpty;`, which is definitely something else... Is it?

Comment: @onnodb: Indeed. Delphi 5 does what your function does, but in addition checks for varEmpty and varUnknown. Still, I doubt that such a change would have been made if it resulted in changed behaviour. Or would that be me being too starry-eyed?

Comment: @mghie: Yes, it's strange, but true. That line in my previous comment is the *only* one in the `VarIsEmpty` function in my D2007 sources of Variants.pas.

Answer (score 2):

Does VarIsEmpty (different than VarIsNull) not do what you want?

Comment: Perhaps problematic is that VarIsEmpty does not handle varErrors returned by Excel.

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure `Empty` is something quite different than `Nothing` --- the latter doesn't seem to have *any* equivalent in Delphi. (I might be wrong, of course, but I'm pretty sure I checked this). Thanks, though!