# Look for header variables using OleFunction "find" inside of an Excel template and replace them from C++

Tags: c++, excel, vba, interface, ole

My problem is the following:

I open an Excel - File and I don't know which of the possible header-variables my clients have used in the template file. These can be: #DATE, #TIME, #NAME and so on. So I need to look for these variables and if the have been used: Replace them.

```
vCell = findCell("DATE");
tempStr = DateToStr(Date()) ;   // Date
if (vCell.VType != VT_EMPTY )
    vWorksheet.OlePropertyGet("Cells", vCell.OlePropertyGet("Address")).OlePropertySet("Value",StringToOleStr(tempStr));
```

findCell looks like this:

```
Variant __fastcall TClassExcel::findCell(AnsiString Cell,String Range){
    // Range is set to A1:Z100 as default in the header file 
    vRange = vWorksheet.OlePropertyGet("Range",StringToOleStr(Range));
    return vRange.OleFunction("Find", StringToOleStr("#"+Cell));
}
```

The line `if (vCell.VType != VT_EMPTY)` does not detect if there is no such cell inside of the header. I also tried `vCell.Empty()` and it did not work out. `Vtype` = 9 if I watch the value. So, I am looking for the corresponding "***If Not cell Is Nothing Then***" of VBA

This reference is to the MSDN library to the find method: [MSDN Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195730%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to be sure to NOT try to write some Variables into a Cell that does not exist.

Comment: Never worked with C++ but what happens when you try `if (vCell != VT_EMPTY )` or `if (vCell != NULL )`

Comment: Both of your mentioned suggestions are invalid Variant operations and lead to an error! Any more ideas??

Comment: Well, I made a lot of tests and to advance I am now using "if (vCell.intVal != 0)" => If the find Method returns nothing the integer value is 0, in all other cases it has another value, So for the moment this works fine, but if anyone has a better idear... go ahead! These are my intents 
if (!vCell.IsNull()){
   pr = 1;
}
if (!VarIsEmpty(vCell)){
   pr = 2;
}
if (!VarIsNull(vCell)){
   pr = 3;
}
if (vCell != 0){
   pr = 4;
}
if (vCell.intVal != 0){
   pr = 5;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for the Variant value "Nothing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/577894/checking-for-the-variant-value-nothing)